# OnDestroyActionMode() interrupted onActionItemClicked()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I have an action item called delete, which gets an ArrayList that I have created and removes all the Contacts that are checked (based on a boolean variable that I have in the class Contact).

Everything is good when I click delete and it's one item, but if it's more than 6 items, onDestroyActionMode method interrupts my onActionItemClicked method and some items are left not deleted. How do I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class ContactViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactViewAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "AKS";

private AppCompatActivity mActivity;
private List<Contact> contactList;
public ActionMode mActionMode = null;
public ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_mode_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_mode_delete:
                for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "size " + String.valueOf(contactList.size()));
                    if (contactList.get(i).isSelected) {
                        contactList.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        for (Contact c : contactList) {
            c.isSelected = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyActionMode");
        }
        mActionMode.finish();
        mActionMode = null;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public TextView contactName;
    public TextView contactMoneyOwed;
    public ImageView contactPhoto;
    public CheckBox isCheckedBox;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        contactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        contactMoneyOwed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_money_owed);
        contactPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
        isCheckedBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemCheckBox);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean everythingIsUnchecked = true;
        for (Contact c : contactList) {
            if (c.isSelected) {
                everythingIsUnchecked = false;
            }
        }
        if (!everythingIsUnchecked) {
            isCheckedBox.setChecked(!isCheckedBox.isChecked());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        isCheckedBox.setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
}

public ContactViewAdapter(List<Contact> contactList, AppCompatActivity activity) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ContactViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, final int position) {
    contactViewHolder.contactName.setText(contactList.get(position).name);
    contactViewHolder.contactMoneyOwed.setText(contactList.get(position).moneyOwed);
    contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setImageResource(contactList.get(position).photoID);
    contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setOnTouchListener(null);
    contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setChecked(contactList.get(position).isSelected);

    if (contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.isChecked()) {
        contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
            contactList.get(position).isSelected = isChecked;
            boolean everythingIsUnchecked = true;
            for (Contact c : contactList) {
                if (c.isSelected) {
                    everythingIsUnchecked = false;
                }
            }
            if (mActionMode == null) {
                mActionMode = mActivity.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            } else if (everythingIsUnchecked) {
                mActionMode.finish();
                mActionMode = null;
            }
            if (isChecked) {
                contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                contactViewHolder.isCheckedBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                contactViewHolder.contactPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
    }

}
```

And here's what I get from the log:

```
10-03 19:47:23.181 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 0
10-03 19:47:23.413 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 1
10-03 19:47:23.789 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 2
10-03 19:47:24.067 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 3
10-03 19:47:24.453 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 4
10-03 19:47:25.115 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 5
10-03 19:47:26.350 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 6
10-03 19:47:26.734 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 7
10-03 19:47:27.046 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 8
10-03 19:47:27.468 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 9
10-03 19:47:27.812 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: 10
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 11
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 10
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 9
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 8
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 7
10-03 19:47:29.658 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: size 6
10-03 19:47:29.659 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: onDestroyActionMode
10-03 19:47:29.659 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: onDestroyActionMode
10-03 19:47:29.659 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: onDestroyActionMode
10-03 19:47:29.659 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: onDestroyActionMode
10-03 19:47:29.659 1962-1962/com.example.andreassavva.expensemanager D/AKS: onDestroyActionMode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My for-loop sucks. I needed to change it to

```
for (int i = contactList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (contactList.get(i).isSelected()) {
                            contactList.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
```

instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use extreme caution when removing items from a Collection while iterating over it. You can use an 'Iterator' to do so safely while preserving the order of iteration. Your solution iterates from the end of the list. Please see edit.

Comment: Why is it worse to start from the end of the list?

Comment: I never said that. Use 'Iterator' if you want to start from the beginning of the list. Your original for does that. Thought you might want to preserve that behavior.

Comment: ah, ok! Nah, it doesn't really matter, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

`ActionMode.finish()` calls `onDestroyActionMode()`. So remove the call to `finish()` from your `onDestroyActionMode()` implementation. New implementation becomes:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    for (Contact c : contactList) {
        c.isSelected = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyActionMode");
    }
    //mActionMode.finish();
    mActionMode = null;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Since you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onDestroyActionMode()`, remove that call from your implementation of `onActionItemClicked()`. New `onActionItemClicked()` implementation becomes:

**EDIT:**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_mode_delete:
            Iterator<Contact> contactIterator = contactList.iterator();
                while(contactIterator.hasNext()) {
                  Contact contact = contactIterator.next();
                  if (contact.isSelected) {
                     contactIterator.remove();
                  }
                }
                //notifyDataSetChanged();

                mode.finish();// This calls 'onDestroyActionMode()'
                // and it will notify the data set change.
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did this, still doesn't work, onDestroyActionMode() is still called!

It seems that onDestroyActionMode() is called during the for-loop, so it interrupts the for-loop to be called. Any ideas as to why this is happening?